# trying to animate an element to different positions using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

based on this [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_animate.asp) tutorial on w3 schools I wrote a function(move) that animates an element(div) using the setInterval() method, my problem is when I try to call the function move() several times the div does an unexpected behavior, I tried to use async/await but it didn't work.

```js
async function moveArray(destination) {
  //move through array of addresses
  for (let i = 0; i < destination.length - 1; i++) {
    await move(destination[i], destination[i + 1]);
  }
}

async function move(pos, add) {
  //moves element from position to address
  var elem = document.getElementById("object");
  var id = setInterval(frame, 15);

  function frame() {
    if (pos.x == add.x && pos.y == add.y) {
      clearInterval(id);
      return;
    } else {
      //if element haven't reached its target
      // we add/substract 1 from the address and update styling
      if (pos.x != add.x) {
        pos.x += add.x > pos.x ? 1 : -1;
        elem.style.left = pos.x + "px";
      }
      if (pos.y != add.y) {
        pos.y += add.y > pos.y ? 1 : -1;
        elem.style.top = pos.y + "px";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}

#object {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="moveArray( [{x:0,y:0}, {x:140, y:150}, {x:130, y:110}, {x:70, y:65}] )">
      move
    </button>
<div id="container">
  <div id="object"></div>
  //object to be animated
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weird behavior is caused because the `move` function is being called multiple times simultaneously in the `for` loop. This happens because your async functions do not know when they are done.

Instead of making `move` async, which it doesn't have to if it is not awaiting anything, return a `Promise` from the start and call you animation code inside of it. When the point is reached when animation has to end, `resolve` the promise.

Doing it like this will make your `await` statement in the `for` loop wait for the `move` function to reach the `resolve` call before continuing with the next animation.

```js
async function moveArray(destination) {
  //move through array of addresses
  for (let i = 0; i < destination.length - 1; i++) {
    await move(destination[i], destination[i + 1]);
  }
}

function move(pos, add) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    var elem = document.getElementById("object");
    var id = setInterval(frame, 15);

    function frame() {
      if (pos.x == add.x && pos.y == add.y) {
        clearInterval(id);
        
        // Fulfill promise when position is reached.
        resolve();
        
      } else {
        if (pos.x != add.x) {
          pos.x += add.x > pos.x ? 1 : -1;
          elem.style.left = pos.x + "px";
        }
        if (pos.y != add.y) {
          pos.y += add.y > pos.y ? 1 : -1;
          elem.style.top = pos.y + "px";
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #container {
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      position: relative;
      background: yellow;
    }
    
    #object {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      position: absolute;
      background: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="moveArray( [{x:0,y:0}, {x:140, y:150}, {x:130, y:110}, {x:70, y:65}] )">
      move
    </button>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="object"></div>
    //object to be animated
  </div>
  <script src="animation.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```